# VSTS release level "Windows PowerShell Cannot Run Script Whose Path Contains Spaces"

Tags: powershell, spaces, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I worked on DevOps with VSTS. Currently I used the “PowerShell” Task to run the PowerShell script. But unfortunately my VSTS repository name having space (for example “WebApp Demo”), that’s why I am getting the issue while executing the PowerShell script at VSTS release level.

> [error] Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written
>   to the error stream.

PowerShell Task configuration in VSTS release definition
[image]

For resolving the above error I followed so many blogs but issue will be the same.

1. [Windows Powershell doesn't seem to accept target paths with spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/881019/windows-powershell-doesnt-seem-to-accept-target-paths-with-spaces)
2. [Run a PowerShell Script with Space in the Path](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/07/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path/)
3. [Windows PowerShell Cannot Run Script Whose Path Contains Spaces](http://blog.danskingdom.com/fix-problem-where-windows-powershell-cannot-run-script-whose-path-contains-spaces/)

Comment: This is a long shot but did you try encapsulating the script path in double quotes?

Comment: It should work, add System.debug variable and set the value to true, then start release and share this log on the OneDrive.

Comment: @Persistent13, I already tried with double quotes, but it won't be work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the log, you the value of **ConfigFilePath** is the path that contains space.

Change argument to:

`-webConfigFilePath "$(ConfigFilePath)"`